# Java String to Integer No Working?

Tags: java, mysql

I have the following class and when I run it I get an error which is:

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "com.mysql.jdbc.JDBC4ResultSet@42147df5"
```

The error occurs on this line:

```
fono = Integer.valueOf(fonoS);
```

This is the Code:

```
public Counter(){
    String query = "SELECT MAX(FONO) from forders";

 try {
    connectOrders.pst = connectOrders.con.prepareStatement(query);
    connectOrders.rs = connectOrders.pst.executeQuery(query);
    if (connectOrders.rs.next()){
        Object fonoO = connectOrders.rs;
        String fonoS= fonoO.toString();
        fono = Integer.valueOf(fonoS);
       try {
            serialisationFoNo(fono);
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(Counter.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
    }
    if (connectOrders.rs.wasNull()){
        fono = 1;
        try {
            serialisationFoNo(fono);
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(Counter.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
    }

    } catch (SQLException ex) {
     Logger.getLogger(Counter.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
     JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, ex);
    }
}
```

Why is it throwing this exception I have used the same syntax of code elsewhere in the application and it works.

NOTE: I have also tried using Integer.parseInt(); but even that throws a similar exception.

Comment: The message is pretty clear. You are trying to parse the toString representation of your object (which is `com.mysql.jdbc.JDBC4ResultSet@42147df5`) and that is obviously not a valid integer that you could parse.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't extract integer from your result set. First change your SQL to

```
"SELECT MAX(FONO) as m from forders"
```

and use

```
rs.getInt("m");
```

from resultset

Comment: great that seems to work! Though im getting an error which says Too Many Connections.

Answer (score 1):

The ResultSet hold all column values, which you can fetch by column index (counting from 1) or name.

Also for a PreparedStatement one does not add the `query` parameter, that was done in preparing.

```
  connectOrders.rs = connectOrders.pst.executeQuery();
  //String fonoS= rs.getString(1);
  fono = rs.getInt(1);
```

Close ResultSet and statement.

Answer (score 0):

I guess connectOrders.rs is a ResultSet variable

you are converting that one to string and then to integer which is wrong

the resultset holds a whole row of data (is a kind of a container), you probably want to get one of the values inside and convert that value to string/integer, like this

```
int x = connectOrders.rs.getInt(1); //get first field from the ResultSet
```

Answer (score 0):

You are converting ResultSet object to String and then parsing it. Instead your code should be

```
int fono = connectOrders.rs.getInt(1);
```

Complete applicable code

```
public Counter(){
String query = "SELECT MAX(FONO) from forders";

 try {
    connectOrders.pst = connectOrders.con.prepareStatement(query);
    connectOrders.rs = connectOrders.pst.executeQuery(query);
    if (connectOrders.rs.next()){

//***********your code change here

        //Object fonoO = connectOrders.rs;
       // String fonoS= fonoO.toString();
      //  fono = Integer.valueOf(fonoS);

     fono = connectOrders.rs.getInt(1);


//**************

       try {
            serialisationFoNo(fono);
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(Counter.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
    }
    if (connectOrders.rs.wasNull()){
        fono = 1;
        try {
            serialisationFoNo(fono);
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(Counter.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
    }

    } catch (SQLException ex) {
     Logger.getLogger(Counter.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
     JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, ex);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to convert whole resultset into integer which is invalid

```
Object fonoO = connectOrders.rs;
String fonoS= fonoO.toString();
fono = Integer.valueOf(fonoS);
```

You could fetch the column from resultset which you think would be integer something on these lines using

```
String id = rs.getString(1);//if max(fono) in db is char but can be represented as integer or if its an int field you could do getInt("id") and store it in integer rather than string.
Integer idValue = Integer.valueOf(id);
```

Answer (score -1):

Use a debugger.

Clearly the value of `fonOS` cannot be parsed as `Integer` in that instance.

From [API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#parseInt%28java.lang.String,%20int%29):

> The characters in the string must all be digits of the specified radix
>   (as determined by whether Character.digit(char, int) returns a
>   nonnegative value), except that the first character may be an ASCII
>   minus sign '-' ('\u002D') to indicate a negative value or an ASCII
>   plus sign '+' ('\u002B') to indicate a positive value.

Comment: Not the DV.. I guess the DV was expecting a *more* detailed answer.